# JavaScript if-else condition to change CSS width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wonder if anyone can tell me why this isn’t working?

```
$(function() {
    $("#header").click(function() {
        if ($(".menuBody").css('width') == 0) {
            $(".menuBody").delay(0).animate({"width": "350"}, 500);
        }
        else if ($(".menuBody").css('width') == 350){
            $(".menuBody").delay(400).animate({"width": "0"}, 500);};
        });
});
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript. What errors do you get? Please post a [mcve] in your question

Comment: This is actually jQuery, too.

Answer (score 2):

The `.css('width')` does not equal a number. It equals a string. Use `.width()` instead.

```
$(function() { 
  $("#header").click(function() {
    if ($(".menuBody").width() == 0) { 
      $(".menuBody").delay(0).animate({"width": "350"}, 500); 
    } 
    else if ($(".menuBody").width() == 350){ 
      $(".menuBody").delay(400).animate({"width": "0"}, 500);
    }
  }); 
});
```

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: This worked like a charm!  You are amazing, sorry for the simple problem.  Im sure I will have more in a bit!

Answer (score 1):

try this code to fix your problem:

```
$(function() {
  $("#header").on('click', function() {
    if ($(".menuBody").width() == 0) {
      $(".menuBody").delay(0).animate({"width": "350px"}, 500);
    }
    else if ($(".menuBody").width() == 350){
      $(".menuBody").delay(400).animate({"width": "0"}, 500);
    }
  });
});
```

**EDIT:**
use `.width()` instead of `.css('width')`;

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot to go on, but maybe because in line 4 and 6 your width is a string : "350" and not an integer: 350